# VBA SCRAPING TABLE returning date to excel sheet instead of actual website text

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, scrape

hi im trying to scrape a webpage table using VBA but some of the columns are returning wrong text usualy comes back numbers and dates.

i have tried scraping with the ie browser and also tried the none browser approach but
both fail to return the correct text.
Here are both the codes.
errors appear in sheet1 columns F,J,K,L

'CODE 1

```
   Option Explicit

    Public Sub GetTableB()

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:O1500").Clear

    Dim ig As Object
    Dim urlc As String
    urlc = "https://www.totalcorner.com/match/today"

    Set ig = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ig.Visible = True
    ig.navigate urlc
    Do While ig.busy: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until ig.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

    Dim tb As HTMLTable

    Set tb = ig.document.getElementById("content_container")
    'Set tb = ig.document.getElementsByClassName("main_content")


    Dim rowcounter As Integer
    Dim columncounter As Integer
    rowcounter = 4
    columncounter = 2
    Dim tro As HTMLTableRow
    Dim tdc As HTMLTableCell
    Dim thu

    Dim mys As Worksheet
    Set mys = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    For Each tro In tb.getElementsByTagName("tr")
   'loop thru table header
    For Each thu In tro.getElementsByTagName("th")
    mys.Cells(rowcounter, columncounter).Value = thu.textContent
    columncounter = columncounter + 1
    Next thu

    'loop thru table cells
    For Each tdc In tro.getElementsByTagName("td")
    mys.Cells(rowcounter, columncounter).Value = tdc.textContent
    columncounter = columncounter + 1
    Next tdc
    columncounter = 1
    rowcounter = rowcounter + 1
    Next tro

    ig.Quit

    End Sub`
```

'CODE 2

```
   `Option Explicit
    Public Sub GetTableNB()

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:O1500").Clear


    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, hTable As Object, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument         '<  VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting  Runtime
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.totalcorner.com/match/today", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    Set hTable = html.getElementById("content_container")
    Dim td As Object, tr As Object, th As Object, r As Long, c As Long
    For Each tr In hTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        r = r + 1: c = 1
        For Each th In tr.getElementsByTagName("th")
            ws.Cells(r, c) = th.innerText
        Next
        For Each td In tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
            ws.Cells(r, c) = td.innerText
            c = c + 1
        
       
       Debug.Print hTable.innerText
            
            
        Next
    Next
    End Sub`
```

Comment: Try formatting those columns as text (`.NumberFormat = "@"`) ***before*** writing the data to them.

Comment: @ Ron Rosenfeld ,works great. All your help is appreciated - thanks! .SOLVED.

Comment: Hi one last thing I just recently noticed that the solution works well this Code 1 wich is the the ie browser code.But when trying to run the more preferred faster Code 2 it keeps coming up the error object or block not set any help or a pointer the right direction would be greatly appreciated ,thanks

Comment: That is a completely different issue. I suggest you post a new proper question concerning that particular issue with full details.

Comment: Ok Ron, will do,thanks again.